# C# Socket Arbitrarily Refused -

Tags: c#, windows, sockets

So, I'm running a windows sever 2008 vps. On this vps I am running multiple server applications including an instance of IIS 8.0. The trouble I'm having is some times (for long period of times, like a day) I'm unable to connect to one of the server applications, and yet able to connect to one of the others. It seems to alternate. The client/server works on a local instance, and worked yesterday so I DON'T THINK it's the code. I also have video of it working because as it so happens I was making a screencast. So I know I didn't imagine it.

So I guess my question is what could be causing this behavior? I'm running on different ports - my only real idea right now is an issue with the vps itself.

Comment: " The client/server works on a local instance, and worked yesterday so I know it's not the code." - that logic is flawed. (still flawed)

Comment: I said works on a local instance and worked yesterday. :)

Comment: It's 99% your code at fault. So start with that mindset.

Comment: I'm not sure what evidence you're basing that off. Obviously that was my first assumption.

Comment: you started off by saying "....so I know it's not the code" - THAT's what I'm basing that comment off!

Comment: Most helpful. The code has been running fine for literally months. I'm sorry   my wording offended you or that you felt the need to share. I already told you edited it.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that for some reason when I added an exception to the windows firewall, it didn't automatically allow it to access the local/home network.

I checked this box, and that seems to have resolved the problem.

[image]

Comment: Maybe now people won't base their opinion on someone's ability based on their stack score. Good one.